# Help understanding the proof of Konig’s minimax theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I am reading the appendix of  A Course on Large Deviations with an
Introduction to Gibbs Measures, by Rassoul-Agha.  Consider the following section

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

---

I am having trouble with the highlighted parts

1. About the first one: I don't get how they used the result of exercise A.13 to argue that we can choose $(t_1,....,t_k)\in M_k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k t_ih(x_i)\in K$. I found the original paper the author used to rewrite this proof here
   [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226962484_A_simple_proof_for_Konig's_minimax_theorem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226962484_A_simple_proof_for_Konig%27s_minimax_theorem)
   , maybe that can help how is he using that so called density of $M_k$

About the second one

2. I don't get how the previous arguments lead to conclude that there exists $p\in K^\circ$ (why does it have to be in the interior?) such that $h_1(\mathscr X)\subseteq \prod_{j=1}^n(-\infty, p_j].$ (how do I get this inclusion?)
3. Again I don't get how they used the result of exercise A.13 to argue the existence of $t\in M_n$ close enough to $\delta$ such that the hyperplane $\sum_{j=1}^nt_ju_j=0 $ (where did this come from?) separates $h_1(\mathscr X)$ and $K$. and why does that imply $\sum_{j=1}^nt_jf(x,y_j)\le c_1$. While this last equation means is  that $h_1(\mathscr X)$ is to one side of the plane, but why isn't it on the other side?

Could you help me understand these points?

**Quoted properties:**

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 This point is standard. It is obvious for a topologist, because it follows from the continuity of the linear space operations as follows. Namely, The map $m:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R^n$ such that $m(t_1,\dots,t_k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} t_ih(x_i)$ for each $(t_1,\dots,t_k)\in\mathbb R^k$ is continuous. Let $\Lambda=\left\{ (t_1,\dots,t_k)\in [0,1]^k:\sum_{i=1}^{k} t_ih(x_i)=1\right\}$. Then the restriction of $m$ on $\Lambda$ is continuous too. Since the set $M_k$ is dense in $\Lambda$, the set $m(M_k)$ is dense in $m(\Lambda)$. Since $K^\circ\cap m(\Lambda)$ is a neighborhood of $m(s_1,\dots,s_k)$ in $m(\Lambda)$, there exists $t=(t_1,\dots,t_k)\in M_k$ such that $m(t)\in K^\circ\cap m(\Lambda)\subset K$.

2 This point is straightforward. Namely, it suffices for each $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ choose $p_j>0$ such that the set $\{x\in\mathcal X: f(x,y_j)\ge p_j\}$ is empty. The conditions $p_j>0$ provide that $(p_1,\dots,p_n)\in K^\circ$.

3 Figure 1 provides some geometric intuition, but I needed the following adjustment to prove the required claim. Put $p=\max\{\max_{j=1}^n p_j-c_1\},1\}$ and $d'=\min\{d,1\}$. We have $\delta\in\Lambda$, so $\delta_r\ge\tfrac 1n$ for some $r\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. For each $j\in \{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{r\}$ put $U_j=\left(\delta_j,\delta_j+\tfrac{d'}{4n^2p}\right)$,
$U_r=(\delta_r-\tfrac{d'}{4np},\delta_r)$, and $U=\prod_{j=1}^{n} U_j$.
It is easy to see that the intersection $U\cap\Lambda$ is nonempty (and open in $\Lambda$).
Since $M_n$ is dense in $\Lambda$, there exists a point $t\in U\cap\Lambda\cap M_n$.
Note that $t_r\ge \tfrac 1n-\tfrac{1}{4n}\ge \tfrac{1}{2n}$.

Let $x\in\mathcal X$ be any point. For each $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ put $h_j=f(x,y_j)-c_1$.

If $h_r<-2np$ then
$$\sum_{j=1}^n t_jh_j\le 
  \sum_{j=1,\,j\ne r}^n t_j(p_j-c_1)-2npt_r\le 
  \sum_{j=1}^n t_jp-2np\frac{1}{2n}=p-p=0.$$

If $h_r\ge -2np$ then
$$\sum_{j=1}^n t_jh_j=
\sum_{j=1}^n \delta_jh_j+(t_j-\delta_j)h_j\le $$
$$-d+\sum_{j=1,\, j\ne r}^n (t_j-\delta_j)p+(t_r-\delta_r)h_r\le$$
$$-d+\sum_{j=1,\, j\ne r}^n \frac{d}{4np}p+\frac{d}{4np}2np\le 
-d+\frac{d}{4}+\frac{d}{2}<0.$$

Comment: Regarding 1: Why is $K^\circ\cap m(\Lambda)$ an (open?) neighborhood of $m(s_1,...,s_k)$? From the assumption in the second paragraph of the proof, : $s_1,..,.s_k \in [0,1], \sum_{k=1}^k s_k=1$, so $ (s_1,...s_k) \in K$  but not necessarily in $K^\circ$. Besides  $K^\circ\cap m(\Lambda)$ doesn't seem to be open since $\Lambda =m^{-1}(\{1\})$ and $\{1\}$  is closed, $\Lambda$ is closed, then is $m(\Lambda)$ closed? if so, then I don't know if  $K^\circ\cap m(\Lambda)$ is  open.

Comment: Im sum, I would need $m(\Lambda)$ to be open and every $ s_i\in (0,1), i =1,...,k$, but I don't know how to justify it.

Comment: @some_math_guy In $K^\circ\subset\mathbb R^{\color{red} n}$ is required to be not $(s_1,\dots, s_k)\in\mathbb R^{\color{red}k}$, but $m(s_1,\dots,s_k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} s_ih(x_i)$. Next, the set $K^\circ$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, so $K^\circ\cap m(\Lambda)$ is open in $\color{red}{m(\Lambda)}.$

Comment: So what you mean is that $K^\circ\cap m(\Lambda)$ is open in $m(\Lambda) $ because the open sets of the subspace topology over a set (in this case $m(\Lambda))$ are by definition the intersection of this set with the open sets of the initial superset ? If yes, this justifies that  $K^\circ\cap m(\Lambda)$ is open (in the subspace topology). How does one know that you have to work with the subspace topology instead?  Still,  It's clear $(s_1,...s_k) \in m(\Lambda)$ but why is it in $K^\circ$? Maybe you said it in your first sentence, but I don't get it because it's grammatically weird.

Comment: **I meant $m(s_1,...s_k) \in m(\Lambda)$

Comment: @some_math_guy If $A\subset B$ are subsets of a topological space $X$, and it is said that $A$ is open $\color{red}{in}$ $B$ then it is meant that $A$ is an open set of the subspace $B$ of $X$, endowed with the induced topology. Next, $m(s_1,\dots, s_k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} s_ih(x_i)\in K^\circ$, according to the sentence preceding the first highlighted part of the proof.

Comment: @some_math_guy I completed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will carefully read the rest. Question 2 is missing the part about "$h_1(\mathscr X)\subseteq \prod_{j=1}^n(-\infty, p_j].$ (how do I get this inclusion?)"

Comment: Also since you are familiar with the problem let me ask you, in the third paragraph of the proof when they apply Hahn-Banach to separate the sets $\overline {\text{co}}(h(\mathscr X))$ and $K^\circ$, how do I ensure that the former is non-empty? It's a hypothesis of the Bahn-Banach theorem that the sets should be non-empty

Comment: @some_math_guy The inclusion follows from the condition $\{x\in\mathcal X: f(x,y_j)\ge p_j\}=\varnothing$ for each $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. The set $\overline{\operatorname{co}}(h(\mathcal X))$ is nonempty because it contains the image $h(\mathcal X)$ of the nonempty set $\mathcal X$.

Comment: When you say that you needed an adjustment for part 3, do  you mean you are correcting or changing something in the original problem or solution, ie. there was an error?

Comment: @some_math_guy The respective claim was illustrated by Figure 1, but no its proof were provided. So I had to write it. The adjustment was not straightforward and was needed for the proof.